# How to authenticate myself as root over rsync+ssh into a remote server?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am trying to use the `rsync` command but I am getting "permission denied" because the pi user hasn't permission to write without the sudo command

I am trying to move my apache2 folder from 10.0.2.2 to pi@10.0.2.21 with

```
sudo rsync -av /etc/apache2 pi@10.0.2.21:/etc/
```

So the big question is, is there anyway to provide the rsync a sudo command for the pi user ? or somthing else without granting the pi user full access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Dear downvoter, the target is a raspberry pi and therefore we have an root user.*

---

You can use the `root` user instead of `pi`. But before you need a password for the `root` user.

Open a ssh connection

```
ssh pi@10.0.2.21
```

And set a `root` password

```
sudo su -
passwd
```

Now you can use

```
rsync -av /etc/apache2 root@10.0.2.21:/etc/
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method when a root login is available is:

```
rsync -av /etc/apache2 root@10.0.2.21:/etc/
```

Note: there is no need for `sudo rsync` if all configuration files in `/etc/apache2` are world-readable.

If you do not mind some additional interactive commands involving `sudo` on the pi, try this approach:

1. Pack all files (files in `/etc` are generally small, so it should not be an issue to pack everything):

   ```
   tar -czC /etc apache2 | ssh pi@10.0.2.21 'cat > /tmp/apache2.tar.gz'
   ```
2. Uncompress all files on the pi:

   ```
   sudo tar -xzf /tmp/apache2.tar.gz -C /etc
   ```

There is a third possibility that involves configuring a rsync daemon, but this requires more effort and might be less secure since the wire protocol is unencrypted and may grant access to anyone who can connect to the daemon.